# How to setup Inno Setup plugin in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, inno-setup

I tried to create exe file of my code, in JavaFX, using NetBeans.
I installed Inno Setup on my system, but still it gives error:

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "iscc" (in directory "D:\Ami\DhruwCreation\Album\June2016\01-June-2016-Integrated\DisplayImageAndUpload"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>
> D:\Ami\DhruwCreation\Album\June2016\01-June-2016-Integrated\DisplayImageAndUpload\nbproject\build-native.xml:441: Error:
>
> JavaFX native packager requires external Inno Setup 5+ tools installed and included on PATH to create EXE installer. See http://www.jrsoftware.org/
>
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

When I click on the error message it goes to `build-native.xml` file and highlights the following line:

```xml
<fail message="Error:${line.separator}${missing.Inno.message}" if="missing.Inno"/>
```

Comment: So did you add the `iscc` to the `PATH`?

Comment: no, i dont know how to add iscc, would you please elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you have to add a path to the `iscc` to `PATH` environment variable.

In Windows Control Panel, go to *System and Security > System > Advanced system settings* and click *Environment Variables* button. Locate the `Path` variable, click *Edit* and add a path to the folder where the Inno Setup is installed. I.e. typically the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5`.

You have to restart your IDE after setting the `PATH` (or even better your machine).